# Convex integer programming on totally unimodular polytope?

Tags: convex-optimization, integer-programming

1. If
   $$\min x'Qx + Rx$$
   $$Ax\leq b$$
   $$x\in\mathbb Z^n$$
   is a quadratic program with $x'Qx$ is convex is there a polynomial time algorithm for this if $A$ is totally unimodular?
2. In particular if we ask that the smallest $x'Qx$ that touches on a vertex of $AX\leq b$ is that in $\mathcal P$?

We know that it is in $\mathcal P$ if $Q=0$. We also know for trivial reasons it will always first touch a vertex point.

> Is it the same for convex case?
>
> If not in what cases can be find minimum $x'Qx$ that first touch a vertex point in $\mathcal P$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of problems are NP-hard even if $A=0$. For instance integer least squares https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/int_least_squares.pdf

Your other question (the optimal vertex) is just as hard - consider binary least squares (ie. the restrict to the unit cube).

Comment: However it seems that if the compact polytope is far away from the origin (the binary cube is close to origin) in a generic position the first point an ellipsoid with center close to origin would hit as it grows in volume would be a vertex point. Also I have a convex objective here.